# Static variable may be dynamically initialized in this header file

Tags: c++

Объявляю глобальную переменную-объект

```cpp
// globals.h
extern A a;

// globals.cpp
A a(5);
```

IDE в h файле выдает предупреждение

> Clang-Tidy: Static variable 'a' may be dynamically initialized in this header file

В чем криминал?

Comment: а что вы пытаетесь сделать для начала? Зачем вам это нужно?

Comment: В этом примере нет никаких статических переменных. Но делать так в любом случае не следует.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch пытаюсь объявить глобальную переменную. Что значит зачем нужно? Хочу получить доступ к объекту из любого места программы

Comment: @user7860670 Как делать не следует?

Comment: объявлять extern переменные и файлы с пачкой глобальных объектов. Если уж хочется получать доступ, то делайте синглетон (предоставляющий глобальный доступ к объекту).

Comment: @user7860670 `cin`, `cout` тоже нужно убрать? Идея то та же самая - получать доступ к консоли из любого места

Comment: @AntonShchyrov вам дело говорят: используйте синглтон для таких случаев

Comment: Если коротко: после такого объявления, если в разных исходниках будут разные  определения. Получится каша, вот и вас предупреждает компилятор не делать так...

Comment: Конечно надо убирать cin, cout. iostream это же самый С++ треш. Они сначала наделали глобальных переменных, а потом чтобы те не страдали от SIOF / SUOF так сильно они решили вставлять в каждую единицу трансляции, их использующую, еще по глобальному объекту-иницализатору...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скорей всего сlang-tidy намекает на то, что неизвестно, в каком порядке будут инициализированы глобальные переменные с динамической инициализацией из разных модулей.

Так например, если в `foo.cpp` есть создание другого глобального объекта:

```
// extern A a;
// ...
Foo foo{a}
```

, то нет гарантий, что конструктор `a` будет вызван раньше, чем конструктор `foo`.

---

Не стоит использовать голые глобальные переменные. Сделай глобальные объекты [одиночками](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) и увидишь, что это хорошо. В самом примитивном варианте — используй [синглтон Меера](https://laristra.github.io/flecsi/src/developer-guide/patterns/meyers_singleton.html):

```
// globals.h

class Globals {
public:
  static A & instanceA();
}

// globals.cpp

A &Globals::instanceA() {
  static A a{5};
  return a;
}

// foo.cpp

Foo foo{Globals::instanceA()};
```